# Convert a nested for loop that returns boolean to java 8 stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have three class i.e. Engine , Wheel and AutoMobile . The contents of these classes are as follows:-

```
class Engine {
     String modelId;
 }

class Wheel {
     int numSpokes;
 }

class AutoMobile {
      String make;
      String id;
}
```

I have a `List<Engine>`, a `List<Wheel>` and a `List<Automobile>` which I have to iterate through and check for a particular condition. If there is one entity that satisfies this condition, I have to return true; otherwise the function returns false.

The function is as follows:

```
Boolean validateInstance(List<Engine> engines, List<Wheel> wheels , List<AutoMobile> autoMobiles) {
    for(Engine engine: engines) {
        for(Wheel wheel : wheels) {
            for(AutoMobile autoMobile : autoMobiles) {
                if(autoMobile.getMake().equals(engine.getMakeId()) && autoMobile.getMaxSpokes() == wheel.getNumSpokes() && .... ) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    return false;
}
```

I have till now tried out this

```
 return engines.stream()
        .map(engine -> wheels.stream()
          .map(wheel -> autoMobiles.stream()
              .anyMatch( autoMobile -> {---The condition---})));
```

I know map() is not the proper function to be used . I am at a loss as to how to solve this scenario. I have gone through the api documentation and have tried forEach() with no result. I have gone through the reduce() api , but I am not sure how to use it

I know the map converts one stream to another stream , which should not be done . Can anyone suggest how to solve this scenario.

Comment: your classes seem to miss some fields. Are you sure the example is correct?

Comment: @Eugene , this is just a small snapshot of the entire project ; so have encapsulated a lot of properties to enhance readibility.

Comment: well make that a *testable* example then. We are guessing here... Also are you sure you actually want *those exact conditions?*

Comment: @Echo I would stick to using your for-loop implementation in this case. It's good enough as it is. You shouldn't always try to use streams just because it should be possible.

Comment: @Eugene , can you elaborate about the testable example ? As in should I write a working snapshot ?

Comment: @Echo exactly, a working example with for-loops for example. Even if it is simplified...

Comment: As a side note, you should avoid boxing your result into a `Boolean` if the method never returns `null`. Just return `boolean` instead. In fact, `null` Boolean's is a recipe for nasty NPE's.

Answer (score 6):

You should nest `Stream::anyMatch`:

```
return engines.stream()
    .anyMatch(engine -> wheels.stream()
      .anyMatch(wheel -> autoMobiles.stream()
          .anyMatch(autoMobile -> /* ---The condition--- */)));
```

Comment: Just as a discussion , the following happens :- The innerMost anyMatch checks a condition and returns a boolean true if any condition matches . The 2nd anyMatch , then checks for a true from the inner block and if there is a true for any instant of wheel , then it returns true and it iteratively goes outward , finally returning true or false. Please , comment if my assumption is correct as it will help in developing the logic.

Comment: @Echo `Stream::anyMatch` is a short-circuit terminal operation. If the innermost `anyMatch` matches it is propagated to the outermost, like the return statement in your nested for-loops.

Comment: so why do I need the other two anyMatch ? Is there any other way of doing it (optimised or more logically sound)  , provided all the factors of this code [ triple nested for loop , a if condition check, returning boolean] etc , remains the same ?

Comment: @Echo Again you need the other two anyMatch because of short-circuiting behaviour like your return statement if the nested loops. These two implementations are equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

You should be using flatMap, not Map.

Comment: Flatmap returns a `Stream`. His function has return type `boolean`.

Comment: He is already getting the boolean from the stream correctly using anymatch.      That's not the part he needed help with.

Comment: His problem is that he gets a `Stream<Stream<Stream<Boolean>>>`, but he wants a `Boolean`.